# Prove that every subgroup of a free group is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, free-groups

Let $F_n$ be the free group of rank $n$ and $G$ be a subgroup. (By the Nielsen-Schreier Theorem we know that $G \cong F_m$ for some $m$, but that's not really relevant I think.) I want to show $G \unlhd F_n$.

Since $G$ is a subgroup of $F_n$, it has the group presentation $G = \langle f_1, \cdots, f_n\ |\ R_1, R_2, \cdots, R_k \}$, where $f_i$ are the generators of $F_n$ and $R_j$ are relations. Then intuitively I should be able to quotient out $R_1, \cdots, R_k$, thus giving a homomorphism from $F_n$ to $F_n / G$ with kernel $G$, so $G$ is normal. But this isn't quite rigorous...how do I formalize this step?

Comment: Note that this cannot possibly be true by the Lattice isomorphism theorem, which identifies normal subgroups of a quotient with normal subgroups containing the kernel. Pick your favorite group $G$ with **nonnormal** subgroup $H$. Then find a free group $F_n$ mapping onto $G$ (using the universal property of the free group),  and pull back $H$. The pullback will be a nonnormal subgroup of $F_n$. If the statement you wanted to prove were true, then every subgroup of every group would be normal in the group.

Comment: Also, you have the idea of generators and relators wrong. A subgroup $G$ of $F_n$ cannot be presented as $\langle f_1,\ldots,f_n|R_1,\ldots,R_k\}$ where $f_i$ are generators of $F_n$ and $R_i$ are relations. That would make $G$ a **quotient** of $F_n$, not a subgroup. A subgroup would be given as $\langle g_1,\ldots,g_m\langle$ ($m$ possibly infinite), where $g_i = w_i(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ is a word in the generators of $F_n$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think this is true.

Take the cyclic subgroup $G$ generated by $ab$ in $F_2=\langle a,b\mid\ \rangle$.

Then $a(ab)a^{-1}\not\in G$, since it is a word with two consecutive $a$'s and elements of $G$ are of the form $(ab)^n, n\in\Bbb Z$ (and the writing of a word is unique, precisely because there are no relations in $F_2$).

Comment: Drat, I should have seen that. Thanks!

Comment: @aras You're welcome!

Comment: More generally, *no cyclic subgroup of a free group of rank $>1$ is normal*.